# Bluetooth installing and loading at install. I dont have Bluetooth?

Tags: system-installation, bluetooth

I have noticed in my install `dmesg` that bluetooth initializes and loads all these drivers for it into the installation. I however don't have bluetooth on my system?

This is very aggravating and it would be great if I could figure out how to stop this. I try to uninstall it but it uninstalls a lot of other dependencies. Why is bluetooth so ingrained in the OS and so hard to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to remove Bluetooth, you can simply disable it while loading system.

#### Disable bluetooth

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

then add `rfkill block bluetooth` line before `exit 0`.